# In two combined plotly.express.scatter_mapbox, the animation is working only for the one scatter_mapbox

Tags: python, animation, plotly, plotly-python

I have combined two scatter_mapbox in one figure but the animation frame is working only for the first scatter_mapbox. My initial dataset was df. I have split it in email and no_email datasets. I wanted to use different colors for the customers that have responded and customers that havent responded with an email.
Here is my code:

```
i="marketing email"
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(email.loc[email['ID'] == i], 
                        lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", color="MAX_VALUE", 
                        size=email.loc[email['ID'] == i].MAX_VALUE.to_list(),
                        animation_frame="MONTH",
                        title=i,
                        color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.Oranges, size_max=13, zoom=4,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
        
fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(no_email.loc[no_email['ID'] == i], 
                        lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", color="MAX_VALUE", 
                        size=no_email.loc[no_email['ID'] == i].MAX_VALUE.to_list(),
                        animation_frame="MONTH", 
                        title=i,
                        color_continuous_scale = 'ice', size_max=15, zoom=4,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
        

fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])
fig.layout.coloraxis2 = fig2.layout.coloraxis
fig['data'][1]['marker'] = {
   'color': np.array(no_email['MAX_VALUE']),
   'coloraxis': 'coloraxis2',
   'opacity': 1,
   'sizemode': 'area',
   'sizeref': .01,
   'autocolorscale': False
}
                 
fig.update_layout( autosize=False,width=800, height=700)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds = "locations", visible = False)
fig.layout.coloraxis2.colorbar.x = -0.2
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data so I have simulated data frames
- key point you missed is integrating the **frames** as well as the **traces**

```
# integrate the frames
for fe, fne in zip(fig.frames, fig2.frames):
    for t in fne.data:
        t.update(marker_coloraxis="coloraxis2")
    fe.update(data=fe.data + fne.data)
```

#### simulate data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate dataframes from earthquake data...
df = pd.read_csv("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.csv")
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df["SPLIT"] = df["magSource"].eq("us")
df["ID"] = "marketing email"
df["MONTH"] = (df["time"].dt.day % 12) + 1
df = df.sort_values(["MONTH","time"])
email = df.rename(columns={"mag":"MAX_VALUE", "latitude":"latitude".upper(), "longitude":"longitude".upper()}).loc[df["SPLIT"]]
no_email = df.rename(columns={"mag":"MAX_VALUE", "latitude":"latitude".upper(), "longitude":"longitude".upper()}).loc[~df["SPLIT"]]
```

#### graphing solution

```
import plotly.express as px

i="marketing email"
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(email.loc[email['ID'] == i], 
                        lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", color="MAX_VALUE", 
                        size=email.loc[email['ID'] == i].MAX_VALUE.to_list(),
                        animation_frame="MONTH",
                        title=i,
                        color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.Oranges, size_max=13, zoom=0,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
        
fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(no_email.loc[no_email['ID'] == i], 
                        lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", color="MAX_VALUE", 
                        size=no_email.loc[no_email['ID'] == i].MAX_VALUE.to_list(),
                        animation_frame="MONTH", 
                        title=i,
                        color_continuous_scale = 'ice', size_max=15, zoom=4,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
        

fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])

# integrate the frames
for fe, fne in zip(fig.frames, fig2.frames):
    for t in fne.data:
        t.update(marker_coloraxis="coloraxis2")
    fe.update(data=fe.data + fne.data)

fig.layout.coloraxis2 = fig2.layout.coloraxis
fig['data'][1]['marker'] = {
   'color': np.array(no_email['MAX_VALUE']),
   'coloraxis': 'coloraxis2',
   'opacity': 1,
   'sizemode': 'area',
   'sizeref': .01,
   'autocolorscale': False
}
                 
fig.update_layout( autosize=False,width=800, height=700)
# pointless - using mapbox !
# fig.update_geos(fitbounds = "locations", visible = False)
fig.layout.coloraxis2.colorbar.x = -0.2
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much for both the solution and the explanation.